# URL Not showing errors / PHP

Tags: php, url, error-handling

So Iv'e been following this guide for a log in system for Uni work (I'm a mere beginner at coding, so don't get upset if its a 'stupid' question. But..

```
<?php

if (isset(filter_input_array(INPUT_POST)['register'])) {
    require 'connection.php';
}

$firstname = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST) ['firstname'];
$lastname = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST) ['lastname'];
$registeras = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST) ['registeras'];
$password = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST) ['password1'];
$repassword = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST) ['password2'];

//error handlers

if (empty($firstname)||empty($lastname) ||empty($registeras)||empty($password) ||empty($repassword)){
    $header = header("location:../register.php?error=emptyfields&firstname=".$firstname."&lastname=".$lastname);
    exit();
}
```

After the IF statement watching the video you can clearly see the `register.php?error=emptyfields&firstname=` in the URL. However in my case, I see absolutely no change. Any veterans out there that may know a solution to this problem. Would be much appreciated!

Comment: What are you expecting to change?

Comment: `$header = header` should just be `header( ..`

Comment: Im expecting to see the error in the URL if say I do not type anything in the firstname field the URL should pop up with the error message saying emptyfield. @RussJ

Comment: @tim still nothing friend.

Comment: This sounds like an issue with your 'register.php' document. Does it contain something along the lines of $_GET["error"]?

Comment: Nope. I do not have anything like that in the register.php. I have simply just made a little form so sign up <input type="text" name="fistname" placeholder="FirstName"><br><br> Like so

Comment: Well that's what you'll need to do. Add a $_GET["error"] to retrieve the error code, then you can do what you want with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need a $_GET["error"] statement somewhere in 'register.php' in order to access this parameter